# Integrating Django (Rest Framework) with ReactJS

Tags: python, django, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework

Let's say I want to join Django Rest Framework with React.
I've read some questions but couldn't understand how to do it.

Can I just make Django listen to another port with Apache, redirect port 80 to my React index.html and make the API calls using Django's port? Or do I need separate servers?

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use webpack and integrate you react code within Django templates. Google it you will find so many things for it

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I think OP want's an API, not just using django to serve templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking you could run both servers on the same host server by setting different ports. 80 being your react `index.html` and some other port being your Django REST Framework API.

You could also host the API and your React app on two different servers if you wished, but here instead of changing the ports, you'd also be changing the domain. In this case you will need to make sure you have set up correct CORS settings in your Django settings.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, I just didn't know if using the same server for different things on each port would be considered bad practice, but I guess that's the way to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It depends on your risks, two servers mean one isn't affected if the other goes down but if you're on one server you won't have to send data outside of the machine, protecting against man in the middle attacks.